# Any JMX library / framework that makes development easier?

Tags: jmx, spring-jmx

I am wondering, do we have any framework / library that makes development easier?
For example, Apache Mina or Netty makes NIO programming easier.

I heard of Spring JMX, MX4J, are they very easy to use?

Answer (score 2):

I've used Spring for it. It's very easy to use (especially if you already use Spring in your project) but it cannot handle some more advanced things (like MXBeans). In my current project we use a lot of the things that Spring offers but have implemented some parts ourselves.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/jmx.html

Answer (score 1):

I like servo which was opensourced by netflix.

See [1].

[1] http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/02/announcing-servo.html?m=1